# Should I use an A record or a CNAME for a wildcard subdomain?

Tags: subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

Some people are saying use an A record and others a CNAME for a catch all subdomain.

Which should I use and why?

Comment: This isn't an alternative - you need at least one A record in any case. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I think what he means is whether he should create separate A records for mydomain.com and *.mydomain.com OR create one A record for mydomain.com and use a CNAME to alias *.mydomain.com to it.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill He'd have an A record for www/no-www subdomains. He's asking whether he should CNAME * to www or use an explicit A record for it.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It won't really matter if you `CNAME` or `A` record the `*.example.com` record.

The one benefit to `CNAME` is that if you change your `A` record for `www.example.com` you won't need to change the `*.example.com` record as well, but that's minimal.

Comment: Ahh yes, that makes sense now

Comment: Can this be clarified? The benefit of CNAME is it points to the (already specified) A record instead of an IP? However the benefit of using another A record is that only 1 lookup is performed? If that's the case, surely an A record is the obvious choice, as there's a benefit for every lookup, as opposed to DNS changes which in most cases will be *occassional* at most? If this is the case I would say it *does* matter quite a bit.

Comment: @cantsay Chances are * and www will be on the same DNS server, in which case most DNS servers will return it all in one lookup.

Comment: @cantsay this answer is a bit vague. An `A` record means that if your server's IP changes for some reason, you need to change the `A` record (this can be bad since it takes up to 48 hours for it to become effective - during which your domain would point to the old ip - which might have gone). A `CNAME` makes sense when you have an alternative name for your server (or your service provider provides one). In that case, if the IP changes, you won't need to worry about it (unless the provider fked up `A` records on their side).

Comment: For example, if you use a custom domain for GitHub Pages or Cloudflare Pages, they tell you to use a CNAME record pointing to `<user>.github.io` or `<site>.pages.dev` respectively, so they can change their infrastructure without having to tell all their clients to switch to a different IP.

Answer (score 66):

I think question is about to understand `A` & `CNAME` records deeply. I have also found this confusing but after reading couple of blogs, I came up with following understanding:

The `A` and `CNAME` records are the two common ways to map a host name (name hereafter) to one or more IP address. Before going ahead, it's important that you really understand the differences between these two records. I'll keep it simple.

The `A` record points a name to a specific IP address. For example, if you want the name `blog.myweb.example` to point to the server `186.30.11.143` you will configure:

```
blog.myweb.example     A        186.30.11.143
```

The `CNAME` record points a name to another name, instead of an IP address. The `CNAME` source represents an alias for the target name and inherits its entire resolution chain.

Let's take our blog as example:

```
blog.myweb.example              CNAME   my.bitbucket.example
my.bitbucket.example            CNAME   github.map.mybitbucket.example
github.map.mybitbucket.example  A       186.30.11.143
```

We use GitHub Pages and we set `blog.myweb.example` as a `CNAME` of `my.bitbucket.example`, which in turns is itself a `CNAME` of `github.map.mybitbucket.example`, which is an `A` record pointing to `186.30.11.143`. This means that `blog.myweb.example` resolves to `186.30.11.143`.

**Conclusion:**
`A` record points a name to an IP address. `CNAME` record can point a name to another `CNAME` or an `A` record.

**Source:**
[Differences between A & CNAME records](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/differences-a-cname-records/)

Comment: should "aestrion.gihub.io" be "my.bitbucket.io"? otherwise i'm confused.

Comment: @Thomas I have fixed typo error and updated my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 13):

A common use for CNAMEs is to map a subdomain to a host under someone else's control.

In the case of "A" record if they change the IP address you don't need to change your DNS entry.

An example of this is [WordPress subdomain mapping](http://en.support.wordpress.com/domains/map-subdomain/). WordPress allows you to have a blog on something like "blog.mydomain.com", but their blogs are cloud hosted and may dynamically change IP address due to server maintenance, failover, or load-balancing. Using a CNAME means that it still works.

Comment: "Using a CNAME means that"...means that what?

Comment: *In the case of "A" record if they change the IP address you don't need to change your DNS entry.* - you mean in case of CNAME, right? `A` records point to IPs.

Answer (score 4):

If you have multiple domain that points to the same site:

**With A record:** every of your domain points to the IP of your site, when your change your server's IP, you will need to update multiple time.

**With CNAME:** every of your domain points to a CNAME, when your server's IP change, you will only need to update the A record of that CNAME.

If you have a domain that doesn't belongs to you, or you don't have the control of what it will be pointing to, you can only use CNAME.